# CORS policy error when google API is called

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I want to make a request to this URL from my angular application:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=<place_id>&key=<api_key>`

This is supposed to retrive the details about a specific place. When I call it directly from the browser, I'm able to fetch the data without any errors. But when I want to do the same only from the application I run into CORS policy error.

I tried to explicitly enable (On google cloud, where I have the API key) the URL I'm requesting from (localhost:4200), I setup an ssl so I can host over https, but none of these did anything.

The code I'm using to fetch the data or show the error:

```
firstValueFrom(this.http.get<ReviewList>(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json`,        {params: params, observe: 'response', withCredentials: true}).pipe(retry(2)))
.then(res => {
    this.Reviews = res.body;
    console.log(this.Reviews);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

`params` contain the api key and place id. I tried to do it withCredential: false, but same outcome.

One option I read on many places is to make the call from the server. The only problem is that I don't have one.

Comment: Are you running that request inside a client side implementation of the Maps Javascript API? If so, it would make sense as there would be a conflict of origin on those requests. And yes, the thing you read on other places is correct, you have to make the call from a server since web services are usually for "server-side" requests. You can use the Client Side Services if you want (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) in which I believe is also available in Angular GoogleMaps Component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/google-maps)